# Scanning order of the kbuild / kconfig kernel build system?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, configuration, configure

I would like to know what is the order followed by kbuild when configuring the kernel and what is the order that it's more convenient to use when writing `CONFIG_` options in the `.config` file .

I have read the docs about kbuild but so far no specs on the order of the operations .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strive to not have order dependencies!

The system starts at the first line of the top level Kconfig file, and processes each line in turn. When it sees a 'source' line, it suspends reading the current file, processes the specified file. When it gets to the end of a file it resumes where it was in the previous file.

Comment: ok, but consider the 3 subfolders `fs` `arch` and `init`, there are configuration options related to them, should I write `arch` related options before `fs` ones ? after ?

Comment: If the options are related to the file system put them in the `fs`, if they are architecture specific put them in `arch`, if they relate to the kernel starting put them in `init`. If they are driver specific put them in some some subdirectory of drivers.

Comment: Sorry, probably I wasn't explaining this in the best possible way, I was talking about the options in the `.config` file, the ones that usually start with `CONFIG_` and what it's their optimal order .

Comment: OK, so you are not adding new options to Kconfig files, you are just providing pre-selected answers for generating a new kernel. The order should not matter, put them in whatever order is simplest for you. the build system will read all of them before it starts processing the Kconfig files.